# Stripe Checkout: Something went wrong

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe checkout (one time payment) into my angular application (deployed on firebase, with server backend on firebase functions), but my checkout gets stuck on stripe checkout page:

```
Something went wrong
You might be having a network connection problem, or the payment provider cannot be reached at the moment.
```

[image]

Here is my firebase functions code:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const createStripeSessionTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = functions.config().stripe.test.secret;

  await execute(request, response, STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
});

const execute = async (request: any, response: any, stripeSecretKey: string) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(request.body);

  const STRIPE_PRICE_ID = body.priceId
  const session = await createStripeSession(body, stripeSecretKey, STRIPE_PRICE_ID);

  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");

  response.send(session);
}

const createStripeSession = async (body: any, secretKey: string, priceId: string) => {

  const stripe = require('stripe')(secretKey);

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [{
      price: priceId,
      quantity: 1,
    }],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: body.success_url, //'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url: body.cancel_url, //'https://example.com/cancel',
  });

  return session;
}
```

I can confirm from firebase functions logs that I don't get any error there. Also, all the request parameters, e.g. priceId, are correctly populated (confirmed with console.log).

But I do see something on browser logs for stripe checkout page:

```
api.stripe.com/v1/payment_pages/cs_test_asdhfjkasfui32uhaisd:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I've triple checked my keys and they all seem correctly configured.

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. Make sure your API keys are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it. Turns out, I was using NgxStripe library to initialize stripe, and was using stripe-js library directly in the application to invoke the checkout process.

Due to this the `stripePublishableKey` was never seen by stripe-js, which led to this key mismatch issue. (Hence the `401 - unauthorized` error).

Passing stripePublishableKey directly into `loadStripe(..)` method (on client side) fixed the issue:

```js
loadStripe('pk_test_mystripekey').then(
  stripe => this.stripe = stripe
).then(
  () => this.createStripeSession()
)
```

Stripe support said that a lot of these issue that are reported to them are indeed due to people using wrong publishableKey-secretKey combinations.

Comment: "Stripe support said that a lot of these issue that are reported to them are indeed due to people using wrong publishableKey-secretKey combinations.". Yes, that is correct. When you get this screen, first thing is to check you are using the correct public key/secret key pair. Especially in a platform setup based on *Connect*, in which it is easy to use the *platform key* instead of the *connected account key*, or the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and just needed to add the correct `publishable key` from https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys to get it to work.

Comment: I had the same problem - adding the right publishable key fixed it for me too. I accidentally added an extra character at the end, but once I removed it, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> Stripe support said that a lot of these issue that are reported to them are indeed due to people using wrong publishableKey-secretKey combinations.

Yes, that is correct. When you get this screen, first thing is to check that you are using the appropriate secret/publishable keys.

Especially in a platform setup based on Connect, for which it is easy to use the `platform key` instead of the `connected account key`, or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem in NextJS using in .env NEXT_PUBLIC before the name of variable, and not use "" after =.

Answer (score 0):

please check Api Key
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

- Publishable key
- Roll key and update your key
- change key in your script